# How do I use blazor server-side inside a razor component library using areas?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an existing **.net core 3.0 preview 7 web application**. My application is mainly **razor-pages** organized into **areas** eg. Admin, Sales, etc. I am able to successfully use a **blazor** component if I put it at the root of the application, however, if I move the component to an RCL I can access the component but it is not responsive (clicking the button for the counter example does not increment the count).

I want to be able to go **localhost/Admin/RazorPageContainingBlazorComponent** or **localhost/Sales/AnotherRazorPageContainingBlazorComponent**

I get this error in chrome dev tools: 
'''
**Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error**

https://localhost:5000/myfeature/_blazor/negotiate 404
'''

I believe this is caused by the signalR hub being mapped to https://localhost:5000/, but I not sure how to add additional blazor hub mappings or how to change blazor.server.js to to use the root hub.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey we also found ourself with the same issue.
A better solution would be to specify 
`<base href="~/"/>`
in the head of the html and just referencing `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"/>`

so

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="~/"/>
</head>
<body>

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

After digging though both signalR documentation and the blazor.server.js file I was able to come up with a solution. Adding the code below to you're layout file configures the signalR hub to use an absolute path instead of a relative path.

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            builder.withUrl("/_blazor");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This allows razor components to be used directly in a razor class library, using area routing.

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that it breaks the routing that comes with the template App.razor. If you aren't interested in routing from the blazor app, you can simply throw the view and template code directly into App.razor

Comment: thanks upvoted... However I'm still looking for a non-hack solution...

Comment: I don't think its a hack. Its just a documented configuration.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Ok but I use a normal asp.net core 3.1 MVC setup. I dont understand why this additional config is necessary in my case...