# Where do I put the blazor.server.js script tag in a RazorPages app?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor, blazor-server-side

Right now I have it at the bottom of the `_Layout.cshtml` layout page that is used by every other page. The problem I'm having is that **pages under the Identity area throw errors in the console when navigating to Identity pages**:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/_blazor/negotiate 404
```

and

```
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
```

These errors make me think I'm doing something wrong with how I enable Blazor Server in my RazorPages app.

So I'm wondering, should I only have the `blazor.server.js` scripts on pages that are actually using Blazor? Is there a way to make it available to Areas that putting it in the Layout seems to not do?

Comment: Do you render Razor Components in your Razor Pages App ? And if you do, please show the related code...

Comment: Do not forget to add Blazor service in startup class

Comment: Yes I use razor components. They render and function properly on the pages where they exist. This is more of a question about how to properly include the blazor.server.js script or configure it so that all Areas in the project load it properly.

Comment: Also note that no razor components exist in the Identity area, yet the console still throws this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this post answers my question:

[How do I use blazor server-side inside a razor component library using areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366355/how-do-i-use-blazor-server-side-inside-a-razor-component-library-using-areas)

By default, the SignalR service uses a relative path and was unable to find the _blazor/negotiate endpoint within an Area. The suggested code change in _Layout will make it use absolute paths and normalize to /_blazor/negotiate wherever you are in the page structure.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is late but incase it help others.

I got this error when I was trying to add blazor to my existing app.

I added:

```
<base href="~/" />
```

at the end of the head tag of the _layout.cshtml file found in the shared folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkju2.png)